# Why is Serilog rolling files before file size limit is reached?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core, serilog

i have the following method to instantiate a logger for each of the modules, that my application will import using MEF:

```cs
public static ILogger GetModuleLogger(IModule module)
{
    var moduleLogFile = Path.Combine(_logsDirectoryPath, $"{module.Name}-{module.Version}-module.txt");
    return new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File(path: moduleLogFile, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 1048576)
            .MinimumLevel
            .Debug()
            .CreateLogger();
}
```

Each of the modules will implement this inteface with one method where this logger will be passed in.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Initializes the module, this method will be called once and is the very first to be called for any module type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="moduleContext">The module context, which contains some information about the currently loaded profile
/// <br/>and provides some interaction capabilities with the application.</param>
void Initialize(IModuleContext moduleContext);
```

The following is how one of the modules implements the Initialize method

```cs
public void Initialize(IModuleContext moduleContext)
{
    // _logger is a private field.
    _logger = moduleContext.Logger;
    _logger.Information($"Initializing module {Name} v{Version}...");
}
```

and immediately 3 log files get creatd with 1kb each with the same log message!, Why is this happening ?

[image: Picture of the file logs being created]

I am using the same configuration for my application it is working as expected.

```cs
static AppLogger()
{
        Directory.CreateDirectory(_logsDirectoryPath);
        Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File(path: AppLogFile, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 1048576)
                .MinimumLevel
                .Debug()
                .CreateLogger();
}
```

Comment: How many times it `GetModuleLogger` called? Are you creating multiple loggers?

Comment: yes `GetModuleLogger` will be called for each module and  a new logger will be created, but as you see in tthe image "Name filter-1.0-module" is the log file for one module which gets its own Logger instance, what am i missing here ?

Comment: Right, but is `GetModuleLogger` being called multiple times with `Name = "name filter"` and `Version = "1.0"`?

Comment: @canton7 i just checked and made sure but no there are no other modules with the same name and version

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint inside `GetModuleLogger` to check when it's called? Is it called more than once with that name and version?

Comment: @canton7 yes i just did that, and yes it is getting called three time. For some reason my DI container is creating the calss, where i am importing the modules and initializing them, three time which now i think explains the 3 log files.

Comment: but why is serilog creating new files if it is the same log file path ?

Comment: Presumably because it's a new `ILogger`

Comment: @proless8 did you solve it? I have the exact same issue. The same three files are made.

Comment: @Junaid it was simply a logic error in my application, i was creating a new ILogger instance 3 times with the same file name and path.

Comment: I have created a static Logger file. I am instantiating the logger object inside the constructor only once. Still, I have this issue.